# Jest test React Router Prompt

Tags: reactjs, react-router, jestjs, react-router-v4

I have a component which contains a React Router `<prompt>` in it and now I want to jest test if this  is shown when the user navigates away from the component and the needed preconditions are satisfied. How can I simulate this navigate away and see if the 'Prompt' being triggered in Jest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe someone would need a solution for this case:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { Prompt, Route, Router, Switch, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { PromptProps } from "react-router";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";

const promptResult = jest.fn(); // jest function which holds "when" value of prompt

jest.mock("react-router-dom", () => {
  const PromptMock: React.FC<PromptProps> = (props: PromptProps) => {
    const history = useHistory();
    if (props.when) {
      history.block(); //simulation of prompt behavior
    }
    promptResult.mockReturnValue(props.when);
    return <div />;
  };

  const originalModule = jest.requireActual("react-router-dom");
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    Prompt: PromptMock,
  };
});

test("Shows prompt on navigation away", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ["/path1"] });

  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/path1">
          <div>
            <Prompt when={true} message={"You have unsaved changes."} />
            <div>Should prevent user from navigation</div>
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/path2">
          <div>Some other page</div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );

  history.push("path2");

  expect(promptResult()).toBeTruthy();
});

test("Doesn't show prompt on navigation away", () => {
  const history = createMemoryHistory({ initialEntries: ["/path2"] });

  render(
    <Router history={history}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/path1">
          <div>
            <Prompt when={true} message={"You have unsaved changes."} />
            <div>Should prevent user from navigation</div>
          </div>
        </Route>
        <Route path="/path2">
          <div>Some other page</div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );

  history.push("path2");

  expect(promptResult()).toBeFalsy();
});
```

Comment: I think in the second test you should be pushing `path1` to history and the `when` prop of `Prompt` should be `false` for the test to pass. At least it's failing for me the way you have it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Jest is the right tool to test this. You would normally use it for unit testing and testing whether the  works as expected should be outside the scope of your unit tests. The thing you want to do sounds more like an integration test.